# Whats the technical term for a filter that allows a non unity stride when sliding it's window?

Tags: digital-filters, terminology

So a 1D mean filter of size two with a sliding window defined as W below could be considered as having a stride of one.

> W<sub>n</sub>=(X<sub>n</sub> + X<sub>n+1</sub>) / 2
>
> V<sub>n</sub>=W<sub>2n</sub>

where as if I were to define a 1D 'stepped mean filter' with a stride of two and labeled U below.

> U<sub>n</sub>= (X<sub>2n</sub> + X<sub>2n+1</sub>) / 2

where the number of samples in U (and also V) would be half that of W.

My questions are the following

1. Is U still a filter (I'm guessing it is even though not fitting with the traditional kernel convolution implementation I associate with filters)
2. What is the technical language one could use to communicate and research questions regarding filter/non-filter such as just given?
3. All though not directly related but since I have the floor is, if  V and U would produce equivalent results (my intuition says no)?

Comment: Google “multirate filters” “multirate signal processing”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *decimating filter*. As such, it serves as a 1/2-rate resampler.